# R: How to shorten data frame values to first character

Tags: r, string, character-encoding, gsub, strsplit

I would like to shorten the values of one column of my data.frame. Right now, each value consists of many letters, such as

```
df$col1
[1] AHG    ALK    OPH   BCZ   LKH    QRQ    AAA   VYY
```

what I need is only the first letter:

```
df$col1
[1] A    A    O   B   L    Q    A   V
```

I have read other entries that suggested to use `gsub`, `stri_replace_all_charclass`, or `strsplit`. But I am afraid I need help to implement this.

Comment: `substr("AHG", 1, 1)`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `strtrim`

```
df$col1 <- strtrim(df$col1, 1)
```

Comment: I didn't know about this function.  I use a similar function  `str_trim` from `stringr` for removing white space.  Thanks for sharing this option

Comment: what if we have to trim backwards?

Answer (score 3):

The stringr package is great:

```
require(stringr)

df <- data.frame(col1 = c("AHG", "ALK", "OPH", "BCZ", "LKH", "QRQ", "AAA", "VYY"))

str_sub(df$col1, 1, 1)

[1] "A" "A" "O" "B" "L" "Q" "A" "V"
```

Comment: Why do you need a package here? The syntax is exactly the same as for the base function `substr`.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is the substring function:

```
df$col1 <- substr(df$col1, 1, 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Robin. 
using the substr or substring function will directly do the trick without having to install any package.

```
df$col1 <- substr(df$col1, 1, 1)
```

or 
    df$col1 <- substring(df$col1,1,1)

use syntax substr (target vector, start place, stop place)

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to shorten the (string) values of an entire dataframe `df`, you can use:

```
apply( df, 2, strtrim, 4)
```

This shortens all strings to 4. Comes very handy for pretty-printing dataframes, too.